# How to trigger a build in Go cd when a commit occurs in Github

Tags: github, go-cd

I am wondering how I would configure a material in GoCD to trigger a build when a commit is made on the linked GitHub account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow "[Integrating GoCD with GitHub](https://www.gocd.org/2015/07/07/GitHub-Integration/)" which uses a pull request workflow on GitHub side.

Each time a PR is done or updated on GitHub, the [gocd-build-github-pull-requests](https://github.com/ashwanthkumar/gocd-build-github-pull-requests) plugin from [Ashwanth Kumar](https://github.com/ashwanthkumar) would kick-in and build said PR, updating its status on GitHub after said build.